# NoMethodError in Account::PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm the newbie, my rails version is 4.2.0 and I install three gem `devise, cancancan, rolify`. When I sign up success, I got this message

```
NoMethodError in Account::PostsController#index
undefined method `role' for #<User:0x007fd84c2afba8>

  def admin?
    self.role.name == "admin"
  end

end
```

I guess the problem is `users`, `roles` the connection is miss. And I try to modify my `user.rb` but not work.

This is my `app/models/ability.rb` code

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :update, Post do |post|
        post.user == user
      end

      can :destroy, Post do |post|
        post.user == user
      end

      can :create, Post
    end
  end
end
```

### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  ############################################################
  # not work
  # belongs_to :users_roles
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_tabe => :users_roles
  # has_one :users_role
  ############################################################

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def admin?
    self.role.name == "admin"
  end
end
```

### app/models/role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

When I sign up I will add a role to first sign up user, this is my `application_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    if User.count == 1
      resource.add_role 'admin'
    else
      resource.add_role 'normal'
    end
    resource
  end
  root_path
end
```

### schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160225105659) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "ckeditor_assets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "data_file_name",               null: false
    t.string   "data_content_type"
    t.integer  "data_file_size"
    t.integer  "assetable_id"
    t.string   "assetable_type",    limit: 30
    t.string   "type",              limit: 30
    t.integer  "width"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "ckeditor_assets", ["assetable_type", "assetable_id"], name: "idx_ckeditor_assetable", using: :btree
  add_index "ckeditor_assets", ["assetable_type", "type", "assetable_id"], name: "idx_ckeditor_assetable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", using: :btree

  create_table "travel_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.text     "note"
    t.integer  "travel_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "travels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id", using: :btree

end
```

Comment: What is the relationship between user and roles?

Comment: I think is `users - users_roles - roles`, I just follow this tutorial [https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial). I try to read the code, and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add

```
has_one :users_role
```

in user.rb

Comment: I try it, and I got a new error message `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column roles.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = $1 ... ^ : SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1`

Comment: rails g migration AddUsersToRoles user:references
which will generate 
  `def change
    add_reference :roles, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end`

Comment: hi, I had added a `user-role` table in my `schema.rb`. so I need the relationship between `user` and `user-role` is that right?

Comment: change :roles to :user-roles then :)

Comment: ok, I got it, but I have a question, I have to create the relationship by myself why? I think the gem will auto create for me, is it right? And I read the document, I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the error message above which is stating that it's missing a column which links the users table with the roles table. 
Did you follow step 1 - 6 at [link](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial)?

Comment: yes, I follow it. In my `schema.rb` add the `users_roles` table, and in the `role.rb` have this code `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles`, but the `user.rb` nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, but I'm not sure the question is table's relationship.

I remove my `user.rb`'s `admin` method

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  has_many :posts

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable



  # def admin?
  #  self.role.name == "admin"
  # end

end
```

And modify `ability.rb`

### ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # if user.admin?
    if user.has_role?(:admin) # modify this line
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :update, Post do |post|
        post.user == user
      end

      can :destroy, Post do |post|
        post.user == user
      end

      can :create, Post

      can :read, Post
    end
  end
end
```